# Using os.path.expanduser with subprocess.call

Tags: operating-system, subprocess, gdal

I am having some trouble with `subprocess.call` and `os.path.expanduser`.

I need to run this script on a computer other than my own, and one issue I have run into is running the script on a pc that's user name contains a space `C:\User\User Example`. I was told in a previous post that I should use args with a list. Howver, I don't understand what that means. Any tutorials or relevant post would be greatly appreciated.

```
# Set varible for gdal_calc

gdal_calc = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL\\gdal_calc.py"

# make dictionary of environmental variables
gdal_env = os.environ.copy()

# modify and add variables
gdal_env["GDAL_DATA"] = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL\gdal-data"
gdal_env["GDAL_DRIVER_PATH"] = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL\\gdalplugins"
gdal_env["PATH"] = gdal_env["PATH"] + ";C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL"

# Set constants
# The pathway to the images files are nested within the '--outfile=' command

inHVZero = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Components\\Zeros\\newHVZeros_.img')
outPlace = os.path.expanduser('~\\\Desktop\\Components\\db_Files\\newHVdB.img')
outVFile = '--outfile='+ outPlace
cmd_HV = ['-A', inHVZero, outVFile, '--calc=10*log10(power(A,2))-83']
#calc_cmd_HV = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL\\gdal_calc.py', '-A', inHVZero, '--outfile='+outPlace, '--calc=10*log10(power(A,2))-83']

inVHZero = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Components\\Zeros\\newVHZeros_.img')
outPlace_1 = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Components\\db_Files\\newVHdB.img')
outVFile_1 = '--outfile='+ outPlace_1
cmd_VH = ['-A', inVHZero, outVFile_1, '--calc=10*log10(power(A,2))-83']
#calc_cmd_VH = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GDAL\\gdal_calc.py', '-A', inVHZero, '--outfile='+outPlace_1, '--calc=10*log10(power(A,2))-83']


subprocess.call([sys.executable,gdal_calc] + cmd_HV, env=gdal_env)
subprocess.call([sys.executable,gdal_calc] + cmd_VH, env=gdal_env)
```

Comment: What specific trouble are you having? Is the script gdal_calc.py stating there is an error?

Comment: Yes, I suggest that it cannot find the pathway `C:\User\User`, then it produces an error cannot find pathway `C:\User\Example` so I am assuming the space in the user name is causing the issue.

Comment: What does `print os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Components\\Zeros\\newHVZeros_.img')` produce?

Comment: C:\Users\User Example\Desktop\Components\Float32\newHV32.img

This is as far as I've made it, unfortunately I haven't been able to produce the "Zeros" file because of the pathway.